# Jquery Can I get all index from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, indexing

I'd like to get all of index with class name.
How can I get an index from my table?

The class name is "no" which is located in tr tag.
I want to use jquery.

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="no">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="no">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="no">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this case I need to get values "1", "5", "6".
Once I use index function I just receive only one value "1".

```
var n_index = $(".no").index(); // 1
```

Can you give me an advice about getting all indexes?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method docs:

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the **position of the first element** within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.
>
> If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an integer indicating the **position of the first element** within the jQuery object relative to the elements matched by the selector.

Thus it gives you one value "1".

To get all indexes for each child element with class `no`, you can simply use jQuery `.map()` and then convert into a simple array using `.get()` method like:

```
var n_index = $("table tr.no").map(function() {
  return $(this).index();
}).get();

console.log( n_index ); //=> returns [1, 5, 6]
```

Here, `n_index` is actually an array with collection of all indexes for each child element. If you want to get string instead you can simply use `.join()` method on it like:

```
console.log( n_index.join() );     //=> returns "1,5,6"
// Or,
console.log( n_index.join(', ') ); //=> returns "1, 5, 6"
```

Use whichever output you prefer.

**Demo:**

```js
var n_index = $("table tr.no").map(function() {
  return $(this).index();
}).get();

console.log( n_index );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="no">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="no">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="no">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) you can do something with every elementi in a collection, in this case you can get the index of each element:

```js
$(".no").each(function() {
console.log($(this).index());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="no">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="no">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="no">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```